# Notepad++ find and copy all specific types of strings in text (updated)

Tags: notepad++, regex

It isn't working. I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> selected **"regular expression"** and searched for `href=".*\.website\.com"` I found nothing I need to search for all instances of `<a href="xxxx.website.com/">` where xxxx changes, is of variable length and doesn't contain a `.`

I need it to find

`<a href="cars.website.com/">`

`<a href="beach.website.com/">`

`<a href="breadloaves.website.com/">`

but not
`<a href="nice.cars.website.com/">`

i figured it out, correct search string is **`<a href="(.*).website.com/">`**

Comment: notepad++ uses regexs (the latest version uses PERL regex) They can be confusing, if you edit examples of you want you want to find into the post, we can try to help you make a regex to find them.

Comment: I put the example into the post when i made it, but since it was html it didn't show. When I want to edit it, someone had already edited out the html, thinking it was spam or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`href="[^.]*\.website\.com\/"` should work.

`[^.]` finds any character, except dots.
If you use `.*`, the regex also matches `<a href="nice.cars.website.com/">`.

Answer (score 0):

In notepad++, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open the find menu, make sure the radio option for regular expressions and selected, and do a search for `href=".*\.website\.com"`

Comment: It isn't working. I hit ctrl+f selected "regular expression" and searched for href=".*\.website\.com"   I found nothing  I need to search for all instances of href="http://xxxx.website.com/" where xxxx changes, is of variable length and doesn't contain a . (dot)

Comment: i figured it out, correct search string is <a href="(.*).website.com/">

Comment: I don't use notepad++, some of their conventions seem to be non-standard.